# How to Merge Byte Files Together in Python

Tags: python, django, byte

I am running into a situation where I need to generate multiple filled PDF forms, I have the data filled out and the 'bytes' file is accessible, but when I attempt to combine the 2 files in their byte representation, nothing happens, the file is overridden and the original is the only thing shown.

What am I doing wrong, this seems like it should be easy.

```
# don't worry about these, they are filled PDFs in byte form, this works as expected.
pdf1 = PDFFormManager.fill_with_jinja(file=template, data=data)
pdf2 = PDFFormManager.fill_with_jinja(file=template, data={})
# here is the issue
print(len(pdf1), len(pdf2))     # 177354 177354
print(type(pdf1), type(pdf2))   # <class 'bytes'> <class 'bytes'>
print(len(pdf1+ pdf2))          # 354708
# when I return this, I only get the single pdf, not the concatenated one
response = HttpResponse(pdf1+pdf2, content_type=f"application/pdf")
```

Comment: @KJ hmm...honestly writing that bit about `len`, I was just initially thinking about/showing the oddness that both objects added together produced a larger file yet nothing is changed. How would you go about writing the two pages together instead of merging for size reasons? Nothing I attempted to do via `join` or using `bytesarray` worked. It produced the same output as my initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to take a step back and use `pypdf` to merge the content from the `writer` object.

For example:

```
pdf = PDFFormManager.fill_with_jinja(file=template, data=data)

pdf_merged_buffer = BytesIO()

merger = PdfMerger()
# merger.append(pdf)
merger.append(PdfReader(io.BytesIO(pdf)))
merger.append(PdfReader(io.BytesIO(pdf)))
merger.write(pdf_merged_buffer)   # now shows all pages combined!

response = HttpResponse(pdf_merged_buffer.getvalue(), content_type=f"application/pdf")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="{}"'.format('file.pdf')
response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)
```